# Determing linear independence of three very simple functions. (2.9-23)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why are the following three functions linearly independent if the first two can be multiplied to get the third?

$$y_1 = x$$ 
 $$y_2 = \frac{1}{x}$$ 
 $$y_3 = 1$$

I am focusing on this for a course in differential equations. We are learning to use the Wronskian determinant to determine linear independence.

Comment: By the definition of linear independence, three functions $y_1, y_2, y_3$ are linearly independent if $a_1y_1+a_2y_2+a_3y_3=0$ holds only for numbers $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$. In your case this holds, indeed: if $a_1\cdot x+a_2\cdot \frac{1}{x}+a_3\cdot 1=0$, for some numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3$, then all three numbers have to be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking linear dependence ($\lambda_1f_1+\lambda_2f_2$), not quadratic $(\lambda_1 f_1^2+\lambda_2f_2^2+\lambda_3f_1f_2)$

[You took $\lambda_i=0,0,1$}]